# Spring MVC handler returns String with extra quotes

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm using Spring 3.1 and I have a handler that should return a String value.
Here's how my handler looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = TEST_HANDLER_PATH, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleTest(HttpServletRequest request,
    @RequestParam("parma1") String param) throws Exception {
    String ret = ...
    ...
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=utf-8");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(ret, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

I also tried annotating method with `@ResponseBody` with `return ret;` at the end.

In both cases, when I hit the service, I get extra quotes around String value (e.g. `"This is a test"`).
I'm guessing this is due to message conversion. That's why I tried defining `Content-Type` header, to hit StringHttpMessageConverter explicitly, to no avail.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out there was a JSON message converter registered in one of the imports.

Comment: Did you remove the JSON message converter? What if you don't want to remove the message converter?

Comment: You can target specific converter using corresponding MIME type in request/response headers. Taking a look under the hood is what helped me out.

Answer (score 24):

Had the same problem.

Just make sure you register a `org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter` as well as your Jackson one so that Strings are treated literally and not attempted to be converted to JSON (with extra quotes).

Just instantiate with default constructor or constructor with your preferred Charset. The media types should be set for you with the standard internal defaults. If you're configuring via code extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` then you just add the converters in the `configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters)` method.

Comment: This worked for me.
Also `StringHttpMessageConverter` must be added to `List<HttpMessageConverter<?>>` before any other converter. The order matters, when you configure them explicitly

Comment: Thank you both. Order does matter. If you are using `extendMessageConverters` you will need to explicitly add the `StringHttpMessageConverter` to index 0.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had *over-engineered* **=)**

Had introduced a converter for bean's `toString` Operations like this:

```
class SerializableToString implements Converter<Serializable, String>
```

restricting that (only to my beans), resolved the issue **X)**

**Note:** debugging with a breakpoint @ `org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.getConverter` helped.

Answer (score 0):

In a related scenario, I had an `IntegrationFlow` for a `GET` that incorrectly requested a transform. Basically the target service would receive the `@PathVariable` as a quote escaped string

```
        return IntegrationFlows.from("getThing")
        .transform(Transformers.toJson())
        .handle(
```

The `.transform(Transformers.toJson())` was forcing the strings to be escaped in the URI, so simply removing it - it shouldn't have been there - fixed the issue.