# String with xml not getting rendered properly

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

I am using jaxb marshal to convert java object to xml. My convert method looks like this:

```
protected String marshallerEx(Tickets tickets) throws JAXBException {

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Tickets.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    // Marshal the tickets list in console
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(tickets, sw);

    LOGGER.info("marshal -> " + sw.toString());

    return sw.toString();
}
```

The problem here is when i print it in logs, the return is coming in proper format. for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tickets>
    <ticket>
        <assignedQueueId>61</assignedQueueId>
        <category>11</category>
        <cause>0</cause>
        <createDate>2015-08-19T13:34:18-04:00</createDate>
        <customFields/>
    </ticket>
</tickets>
```

but when i return it to be displayed on screen(in browser) from my controller, it shows like this:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n<tickets>\n    <ticket>\n        <assignedQueueId>61</assignedQueueId>\n        <category>11</category>\n        <cause>0</cause>\n        <createDate>2015-08-19T13:34:18-04:00</createDate>\n        <customFields/>\n    </ticket>\n</tickets>\n"
```

why is it changing the format? what do i need to do to keep the format maintained to display it on screen the same way as its in my logs?

Comment: it is not clear from the question how does string representation of xml get displayed in a browser

Comment: @AlexErohin: i am returning the same string back to browser. I want to see it in the same format like its getting displayed in logs but somehow its getting changed totally

Comment: How does this string get displayed in a browser? Is it written out by a servlet as a response or is it displayed as a part of html page? What html component is responsible for displaying it? ( It might also be responsible for escaping string characters.)

Comment: @AlexErohin: i'm returning it as `ResponseEntity<String>(marshallerEx(tickets),  HttpStatus.OK);`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to manually set `content-type` of RestController response either to `application/xml` (if you want browser to render xml tree) or to `text/plain` (if you want it to display plain text only). This would force the expected representation.

```
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
responseHeaders.set("content-type", "text/plain");
return new ResponseEntity<String>(marshallerEx(tickets), responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Also, seems like a similar problem is described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293469/spring-mvc-handler-returns-string-with-extra-quotes).